# CS1001 Identifier Expected in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I've been trying fix this error for ages so I can actually look at thee game in play mode. It is a script for enemy AI who will chase the player around.

The error is at (90,32) which is attempting to transform the enemys vision when they attack the player

*The line that is creating the issue is transform LookAt(player);*

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    public Transform player;

    public LayerMask whatIsGround, whatIsPlayer;

    public int Damage = 5;

    //Patrolling

    public Vector3 walkPoint;
    bool walkPointSet;
    public float walkPointRange;

    //Attacking

    public float timeBetweenAttacks;
    bool alreadyAttacked;


    //States

    public float sightRange, attackRange;
    public bool playerInSightRange, playerInAttackRange;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("player").transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Check for attack and sight range

        playerInSightRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, sightRange, whatIsPlayer);
        playerInAttackRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, attackRange, whatIsPlayer);

        if (!playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) Patrolling();
        if (playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) ChasePlayer();
        if (playerInSightRange && playerInAttackRange) AttackPlayer();
    }

    private void Patrolling()
    {
        if (!walkPointSet) SearchWalkPoint();

        if (walkPointSet)
            agent.SetDestination(walkPoint);

        Vector3 distanceToWalkPoint = transform.position - walkPoint;

        //when walkpoint is reached
        if (distanceToWalkPoint.magnitude < 1f)
            walkPointSet = false;

    }
    private void SearchWalkPoint()
        // Will calculate and random point on the x and z axis
    {
        float randomZ = Random.Range(-walkPointRange, walkPointRange);
        float randomX = Random.Range(-walkPointRange, walkPointRange);

        walkPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x + randomX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + randomZ);

        if (Physics.RayCast(walkPoint, -transform.up, 2f, whatIsGround))
            walkPointSet = true;
    }
    
    



    private void ChasePlayer()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(player.position);
    }
    private void AttackPlayer()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(transform.position);

        transform LookAt(player);

        if (!alreadyAttacked)
        {
            alreadyAttacked = true;
            invoke(nameof(ResetAttack), timeBetweenAttacks);
        }
    }
    private void ResetAttack()
    {
        alreadyAttacked = false;
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        Debug.Log("Collison");

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")
        {
            if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>() == true)
            {
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().TakeDamage(Damage);
            }
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Identifier Expected in Unity

Means the syntax is incorrect, meaning you've written incorrect code.

```
transform LookAt(player);
```

should be

```
transform.LookAt(player);
```

whitespace ( ) is not an operator or identifier, and does nothing to the transform. In order to access the properties/methods of the GameObject's `transform`, you use a dot (`.`). In this case, you're accessing the transform's `LookAt` method.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a error:

Change: `invoke(nameof(ResetAttack), timeBetweenAttacks);` => `Invoke(nameof(ResetAttack), timeBetweenAttacks);`